# Linux (debian 9) - root partition full: move directories from / to external drive

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, filesystems, sd-card

I have a Debian 9 system which is installed on a single storage device.

The size of the device is a bit less than 4 GB, and there is a single partition, onto which the debian image has been written.

I cannot remove this device. It is part of an embedded system and is permanently attached.

However, I can add an SD card to the system, as a spare slot is provided for user expansion if a larger FS is required.

My intention is to create a single partition on an SD card, probably a 16 GB one.

I would like to know what directories is it safe to move to the SD card? And how can I do this?

For example, many Linux systems move the /home folder to a separate physical device or a seperate partition.

So I know I can create a /home directory on the root of the SD filesystem. What I don't know how to do is how to tell the Debian system that /home has moved? Presumably I need to copy all the contents of /home on the original file system to the new SD card before telling Debian that it has moved?

I am guessing that I can also move /tmp and /var folders.

**Is there anything else that I can safely move? I presume I should not move /bin, /sbin or /root under any circumstances?**

I have worked with systems like this before, where /home is on a different disk, but I have never had to move it after an installation was finished.

I also didn't know what keywords I should be searching for to find this information - so sorry if it seems like a bit of an amature request. Thanks

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/move-home-directory-to-new-partition-disk-in-linux/

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks, that answers one of my questions

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia If you want to add that link as an answer I'll upvote you since 2 others seem to have posted answers, neither of which are as good as the information contained in that article

Comment: Have you also done general clean up? IE, remove old kernels, run `apt-get clean` etc ?

Comment: @ivanivan yes - there isn't anything I'm aware of on the system that we can delete either

Comment: @ivanivan Perhaps I should have included in my question "are there any directories we can move which will likely get us back a few hundred megabytes minimum?" - our home folder is pretty much empty except for a few basic user config files

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `/home` is not a strictly essential part of the OS makes this more feasible than moving, say, `/usr` to a new device.  If you were moving an essential OS hierarchy, you'd want to shut down and boot from some other `rescue` or live CD or USB filesystem.  That could be anywhere from difficult to not possible on your embedded device.

But since you're moving `/home` we can proceed, cautiously.

First, boot into single-user mode.  Stop non-essential services, especially anything that could write to files under `/home`.  Make sure your `pwd` is not under /home, and then gain root:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ sudo -i
```

Then:

1) Insert your SD card and create a partition.  After you've created a partition, make a filesystem on it that will hold your new `/home` heirarchy.  Let's assume that your SD card partition is device `/dev/sdc1`

```
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

2) Mount the new filesystem on `/mnt`:

```
# mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

3) **COPY** (don't move) or `rsync` your `/home` heirarchy onto the SD card (mind the slashes).  After `rsync`ing, unmount the SD card:

```
# rsync -HAXav /home/ /mnt/
# umount /mnt
```

4) Backup your `/etc/fstab`

```
# cp -p /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.safety
```

5) Identify the SD card filesystem's `UUID` and edit `/etc/fstab` to add an entry to mount that `UUID` on `/home`.  You can find the `UUID` using `blkid`:

```
# blkid /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ext4"
```

Given the above output, your new `fstab` line would be:

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /home ext4 defaults 0 0
```

That's an Ubuntu example since I don't have a Debian system at hand.  You will have to replace the xxxxx... part with the correct UUID of the SD card filesystem, and replace `ext4` with the type of filesystem you used when you `mkfs`'ed the SD card (and confirmed in the output of `blkid`).

6) Rename the old `/home` directory:

```
# mv /home /home.old
```

7) Make a new mountpoint for the SD card:

```
# mkdir /home
```

At this point, you should be able to manually mount the SD card:

```
# mount /home
```

and see content under `/home` that is identical to the content under `/home.old`.
Check the contents carefully, including the ownership and permissions of home directories, and `.ssh` directories, or you may not be able to login remotely when the system reboots.  If possible, start the sshd service and test a remote login to an unprivileged account.

If everything looks good, reboot.  When the system comes back up, check the space available in the mounted filesystems:

```
# df
```

You won't have any free space in `/` yet, because `/home.old` is still hanging around.  You should see lots of space available in `/home`:

```
# du -h /
# du -h /home
```

Once you are satisfied that everything looks good, you can get rid of `/home.old`:

```
# cd /; rm -rf home.old
```

You can `rm /etc/fstab.safety` also, but it's probably small enough that there's little harm in leaving it.